# Catching error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'canProduce')` when trying to use mic with videosdk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, videosdk.live

## Edit

I fixed it by [adding `permissions`](https://docs.videosdk.live/docs/guide/video-and-audio-calling-api-sdk/server-setup/#generate-accees-token-and-integrate-other-apis) during token generation:

```
permissions: ['allow_join', 'allow_mod'],
```

---

## [Reproducible demo here](https://github.com/mkhoussid/videosdk-error)

Whenever I try to toggle the mic, webcam or screenshare system, I keep receiving the error:

```
TypeError: this._mediasoupDevice is null
```

I've looked everywhere online, I wasn't able to get a single relevant result.

Looking into the source code, the program attempts to to call `canProduce` on `_mediasoupDevice`, which obviously fails. I'm not sure why this is happening. Is something wrong with my code or is it something else?

Here's my whole relevant file (backend routes excluded, but you can see them in the above source code):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { MeetingProvider, MeetingConsumer, useMeeting, useParticipant } from '@videosdk.live/react-sdk';
import { startLiveStream } from 'src/features/streaming/redux/actions';
import { IState } from 'src/features/core/redux/reducers';

// Helper function for participant loop.
const chunk = (arr) => {
    const newArr = [];
    while (arr.length) newArr.push(arr.splice(0, 3));
    return newArr;
};

const ParticipantView = ({ participantId }) => {
    const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
    const micRef = React.useRef(null);
    const screenShareRef = React.useRef(null);

    const { displayName, webcamStream, micStream, screenShareStream, webcamOn, micOn, screenShareOn } =
        useParticipant(participantId);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (webcamRef.current) {
            if (webcamOn) {
                const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
                mediaStream.addTrack(webcamStream.track);

                webcamRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream;
                webcamRef.current.play().catch((error) => console.error('videoElem.current.play() failed', error));
            } else {
                webcamRef.current.srcObject = null;
            }
        }
    }, [webcamStream, webcamOn]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (micRef.current) {
            if (micOn) {
                const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
                mediaStream.addTrack(micStream.track);

                micRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream;
                micRef.current.play().catch((error) => console.error('videoElem.current.play() failed', error));
            } else {
                micRef.current.srcObject = null;
            }
        }
    }, [micStream, micOn]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (screenShareRef.current) {
            if (screenShareOn) {
                const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
                mediaStream.addTrack(screenShareStream.track);

                screenShareRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream;
                screenShareRef.current.play().catch((error) => console.error('videoElem.current.play() failed', error));
            } else {
                screenShareRef.current.srcObject = null;
            }
        }
    }, [screenShareStream, screenShareOn]);

    return (
        <div key={participantId}>
            <audio ref={micRef} autoPlay />
            {webcamRef || micOn ? (
                <div>
                    <h2>{displayName}</h2>
                    <video height={'100%'} width={'100%'} ref={webcamRef} autoPlay />
                </div>
            ) : null}
            {screenShareOn ? (
                <div>
                    <h2>Screen Shared</h2>
                    <video height={'100%'} width={'100%'} ref={screenShareRef} autoPlay />
                </div>
            ) : null}
            <br />
            <span>
                Mic:{micOn ? 'Yes' : 'No'}, Camera: {webcamOn ? 'Yes' : 'No'}, Screen Share:{' '}
                {screenShareOn ? 'Yes' : 'No'}
            </span>
        </div>
    );
};

const MeetingView = React.memo(() => {
    const [joined, setJoined] = React.useState(false);

    const { join, leave, toggleMic, toggleWebcam, toggleScreenShare, participants } = useMeeting();

    if (!joined) {
        return (
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    join();
                    setJoined(true);
                }}
            >
                join meeting
            </button>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={leave}>Leave</button>
                <button onClick={toggleMic}>toggleMic</button>
                <button onClick={toggleWebcam}>toggleWebcam</button>
                <button onClick={toggleScreenShare}>toggleScreenShare</button>
            </div>

            {chunk([...participants.keys()]).map((k) => (
                <div key={k} style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    {k.map((l) => (
                        <ParticipantView key={l} participantId={l} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
});

const Landing = React.memo(() => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

    const meetingId = useSelector((state: IState) => state.app.streaming.streamConfig.meetingId);
    const videoToken = useSelector((state: IState) => state.app.streaming.streamConfig.videoToken);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => {
        dispatch(startLiveStream({ payload: { onStart: () => setLoading(true), onEnd: () => setLoading(false) } }));
    }, []);

    if (!meetingId || !videoToken)
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleClick}>Go Live</button>
                {loading && <div>LOADING</div>}
            </div>
        );

    return (
        <MeetingProvider
            config={{
                meetingId,
                name: '<Name-of-participant>',
                // participantId: 'Id-of-participant', // optional, auto-generated
                micEnabled: true,
                webcamEnabled: true,
                // maxResolution: '<Maximum-resolution>',
            }}
            token={videoToken}
        >
            <MeetingConsumer>{() => <MeetingView />}</MeetingConsumer>
        </MeetingProvider>
    );
});

export default Landing;
```

P.S. I'm aware my public and secret keys are exposed here -- new keys will be generated whenever I deploy.

Also, if it matters, I'm using Chrome, but the same issue transpires in Firefox.

Comment: Hey, can you check token validity and confirm that it is valid token?